# Is it possible to display an iframe in a javascript popup?

Tags: javascript, email, iframe, popup

Noob here... attempting to display an iframe inside of a javascript popup upon a user's exit. The iframe should be seen first (within the browser prompt) and should allow the user to submit their email address.

I've had some success referencing [this idea](http://kbeezie.com/cross-browser-exit-pop/), but realized the iframe is only displayed after the user has elected to stay on the page. Here's what I'd  *like* to do with the code:

```
function PopIt() { 
    $("a#trigger").trigger('click');
    window.onbeforeunload = UnPopIt;
    return <iframe src="http://moneymappress.com/pro/su/pop_signup2.html">Your Browser doesn't support iframes</iframe>; 
}
```

After reading up on some of the security issues with iframes and javascript it appears this could be an issue, but I wanted to get a second opinion. I'm, also aware the code wouldn't work as is, but figured it was the easiest way to communicate

If it's the case that an iframe can't be displayed with, what would the next best option be?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload):

```
window.onbeforeunload = funcRef
```

> - `funcRef` is a reference to a function or a function expression
> - The function should assign a string value to the returnValue property of the Event object and return the same string
>
> **Notes**
>
> - When this event returns a non-void value, the user is prompted to confirm the page unload. In most browsers, the return value of the
>     event is displayed in this dialog.

So that's the reason that on the example you've referenced the prompt is shown first.

Comment: It should also be noted that there is nowhere to go from here. You can only trigger the browser's yes/no dialog and you cannot do anything else to block the page unload since this would allow sites to trap users on them.

Comment: I suspected this would be the case. So... if I'm understanding correctly, it would not be possible to return a `<form>` into that dialog/prompt.